# Accessing caches on a html page?

Tags: javascript, caching

When I try to open console on my domain's index.html and try to access

`caches` on Latest Chrome it gives me

> caches
> VM1520:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: caches is not defined
> at :1:1

But, when I do the same process on stackoverflow or any other sites, it gives me empty list of `caches` hence the command works there. So how can I support my website to support the cache method?

I have tried using `navigation.serviceworkers` that also fails

Comment: seems to work on https sites only..

Answer (score 1):

As per:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage

**Note**

Chrome and Safari only expose `CacheStorage` to the windowed context over HTTPS. WorkerGlobalScope.caches will be undefined unless an SSL certificate is configured.